# An EOF error occurring out of nowhere

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, eof

I'm on Rails 4.0.2, and still only develop locally.

Without doing anything (as I know of) I'm getting the following error message: "end of file reached", and the following line is marked red in the error page:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
```

I've tried removing all css rules, but that doesn't change anything.

The error stops ocurring only when commenting out that line.

If it's of any help, my config/development.rb:

```
Verksam::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.eager_load = false
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
  config.assets.debug = true
end
```

Comment: what does your `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` look like?  are you maybe missing the */ at the end of the comment block

Comment: I've run into EOF issues when there were invalid UTF8 characters that somehow snuck into the code.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Clear your sprockets cache by running the following:

```
rm tmp/cache/assets/development/sprockets/*
```

Why this works is beyond me but I've run into the same issue and this always works.  If anyone knows why this is necessary I would be interested to hear.

Comment: This is what I am looking for!
Thank you so much! @Josh